# Why doesn't this .desktop file run on startup?

Tags: linux-mint, x11, startup, cinnamon

I'm trying to get the `sensors` command to run in a console on startup on my Linux Mint 18.2 setup.  I've put the following `sensors.desktop` file into my login user's `.config/autostart` directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Monitor sensors
Comment=Monitor temperature sensors
Exec=watch -d sensors
Icon=utilities-system-monitor
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Monitor;
NotShowIn=KDE;
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

I have another `.desktop` file in there that does run on startup, and this one runs if I double click it from the file explorer, so why does it not run on startup?

Comment: Is it executable?

Comment: It wasn't, but then nor was the other working `.desktop` file.  I made it `ugo+x` and it still doesn't run on startup.

Comment: Change `Exec=watch -d sensors` with `Exec=sh -c "watch -d sensors"`

Comment: It still doesn't run at startup.

Comment: I just tried your script and it worked fine on login. I am using `Xfce4`. Maybe the problem is in `cinnamon`, you can try someother DE

Comment: Erm, no.  I like cinnamon.

Comment: Just install `xfce` to debug the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68619/discussion-between-arpit-agarwal-and-jez).

Comment: If the desktop is parsing it wrong, you can try different approaches: try `Exec=x-terminal-emulator -e watch -d sensors` with `Terminal=false`, or simplify the file by removing everything from the line `StartupNotify=true` until the last line, which are not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue. Change the content of `sensor.desktop` to this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Monitor sensors
Comment=Monitor temperature sensors
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'watch -d sensors'
Icon=utilities-system-monitor
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Monitor;
NotShowIn=KDE;
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

Make sure you have `gnome-terminal` already installed. If you use some other terminal than replace it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, works great.  I did suggest an edit though which changes the suggested `.desktop` file a bit to the one I actually used to get it working.